# Sharing data between two containers in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, nfs

I am trying to share data between two containers using a NFS volume .
I have a nfs shared drive set up in my [server/docker manager] at `var/nfsshare` and this same drive is available at my [client/docker worker ] at `/mnt/nfs/var/nfsshare` ,and I am able to share data .

Steps taken 
Used this location as volume in my docker compose file .
When I use docker-compose up ,to start up my containers ,everythign works fine and I am able to share data.
But when I launch a docker swarm ,the containers in my [client/worker] machines are not able to access the mounted volume.

Here is my compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  workerA:
    image: custom1
    tty: true
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source : test
        target : /data                      
        volume:
            nocopy: true

  serverB:
    image: custom2
    tty: true
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source : test
        target : /data
        volume:
            nocopy: true

volumes:
  test
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=192.168.0.100,nolock,soft,rw   # this is the IP of the host for the manager.
      device: ":/var/nfsshare"
```

What is it that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to find out the cause of the issue .Just posting so that it can help someone in the future .

The client Machine already had an exiting volume with the name SwarmName_test ,and when ever I tried to recreate the swarm so instead of recreating the volume it kept using the older one which was pointing to a different path .

Commands useful which came in handy for debugging 
docker inspect [volumeName/containerName etc]
df [to list out mounts in centOS].

Useful guides
Setup NFS 
https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7
Create compose file 
https://blog.dahanne.net/2017/11/20/docker-swarm-and-nfs-volumes/